# What sites must I trust in order to download software *to a server* using IE?

Tags: windows-server-2012, installation, internet-explorer, exchange-2013, active-directory

I am working at a client site and they are insisting that I download a patch from a server, for local installation. USB drives, copying from my laptop, etc, is not permitted.

The only browser I can work with is IE.  (they oppose me installing Chrome).

Why am I doing this?  I need to download several files to install Exchange 2013, including the one below:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34992
```

When I download the file in Safari, and click `show address`, I get the following URL for the downloaded file

```
http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/C/4/2C47A5C1-A1F3-4843-B9FE-84C0032C61EC/UcmaRuntimeSetup.exe
```

Sure, I could gather a list of URLS to download (from my desktop) and download them directly from the server, but I would rather just whitelist or enable the downloading of files from Microsoft.

**Question**

- How can I download [the following file](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34992) from Microsoft's website on a Windows 2012 server, without installing chrome?

**Things I've tried:**

1. Added download.microsoft.com, *.microsoft.com, and *.download.microsoft.com into Trusted Sites
2. Lowered trusted sites security to "low"
3. Downloading the EXE directly via the link above, (which worked)

Comment: I'd oppose you installing chrome on my isolated network server too.  Download the files you need on your laptop and copy them to the server from there.

Comment: When all is said and done you're presumably doing something the $client wants you to do. I think your $client should be prepared to download the software you require for you if their policies restrict you for doing it yourself. It's what I've had to do when I was working in a secure environment. We would download whatever, burn it onto a cd/dvd, take it into the secure environment and then dispose of it appropriately when it was finished with.

Answer (score 6):

Do it properly, and don't use the server's browser to download software.

You download software from a workstation, either "directly" to the server in question by saving to a shared folder on the server, or you download it onto your workstation and then transfer the file over.  Shared folders, copy and paste through an RDP session, USB drive, or any other method that strikes your fancy.

Comment: I don't have billable hours to convince them to change their policy to do things this way.  I'm not permitted to use USB, nor use my laptop.  I understand your perspective on policy, but that isn't what the client is looking for.

Comment: Not being able to download a Microsoft patch from Microsoft's site, using Microsoft's browser, is exposing me to a bit of unwanted attention/snark from the client.

Comment: @makerofthings7  Well, they sound just... super smart..., which is probably the root of the problem.  The problem isn't Microsoft's browser, it's their policy.  And the answer I've given is the way you protect your servers from the internet. If they don't like that or it makes them snarky at you... well that doesn't make them any less wrong.  You can disable IE ESC temporarily, or compile the list of direct download links.

Answer (score 5):

Compile your list, and script the downloads with something like:

```
$downloads = get-content C:\url.list


$wc = new-object system.net.webclient

$dest = "C:\updates\<filename>"

$downloads | foreach{
   $wc.downloadfile($_,$dest)
}
```

Now, 2 things:

1. I confirms this works on a server with ESC enabled (like it would matter, but MS does weird stuff with their tech)
2. Please replace `<filename>` with the real file name

Comment: Nice idea, I may end up going this route.

Answer (score 3):

Since your client has the rather silly requirement you cannot use your laptop or USB to download the required installation files just temporarily turn off [Enhanced Security Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775800%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), restart Internet Explorer, download the files and then turn ESC back on.

**To enable or disable Enhanced Security Configuration**

In Control Panel, double-click Add or Remove Programs.

Click Add/Remove Windows Components.

Click Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration, and then click Details.

Select the group for which you want to enable or disable Enhanced Security Configuration, and then click OK.

Comment: This is the proper answer for the scenario given.